# With Dropdown Box Show Only Selected Div's But Show All Divs When No Option Is Selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website im making and I found a code on here that was able to help me out. I was able to customize it the way I wanted but now im having issues. I simply want  the page to display all divs when no dropdown box value is selected. Here is my code:

```
<style type="text/css">
websitesubmission {
display: block;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>

<script>
$('#category_faq').on('change', function () {
$('websitesubmission').hide();
$('websitesubmission.' + $(this).val()).show()
});
</script>

<select id="category_faq">
<option selected value="">Select An Option</option>
<option value="information">info</option>
<option value="news">news</option>
<option value="blog">blog</option>
</select>
<br/>
<websitesubmission class="information">info</websitesubmission> 
<websitesubmission class="news">news</websitesubmission>
<websitesubmission class="blog">blog</websitesubmission>
```

Here is the working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fj07nnu3/105/

**(UPDATED TO SHOW WORKING SOLUTION)**

Working solution from user below is located here: http://jsfiddle.net/fj07nnu3/124/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just edit your JQuery function like this:

```js
$('#category_faq').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "") {
    $('websitesubmission').show();
  } else {
    $('websitesubmission').hide();
    $('websitesubmission.' + $(this).val()).show()
  }
});
```

The idea is simple, you have a the first select option with value "" (empty), you have to check everytime select's option change if its value is "" or not.

Comment: Thank you, your answer as everyone else is working. Thank you for contributing, im hoping this thread helps others in the future :)

Answer (score 3):

The most proper would likely be to check if the selected index is the first (`0`), as with it, the individual `option`'s value won't matter.

*From jQuery 1.6 you should be able to use its `prop` method `$(this).prop('selectedIndex')`*

Stack snippet

```js
$('#category_faq').on('change', function () {
  if ($(this)[0].selectedIndex == 0) {
    $('websitesubmission').show();
  } else {
    $('websitesubmission').hide();
    $('websitesubmission.' + $(this).val()).show()
  }
});
```

```css
websitesubmission {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="category_faq">
    <option selected value="">Select An Option</option>
    <option value="information">info</option>
    <option value="news">news</option>
    <option value="blog">blog</option>
</select>
<br/>
<websitesubmission class="information">info</websitesubmission> 
<websitesubmission class="news">news</websitesubmission>
<websitesubmission class="blog">blog</websitesubmission>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the code, the user below you seems to have found a simple solution but I just tried yours and it works fine as well and is just as easy, thank you for contributing. I am marking the other user as the correct answer because he answered 4 minutes before you.

Comment: @AdamTourgeman You're welcome, do note though, that solution is not simpler, and first hides all item and then either show 1 or all. If you take a look at mine it check first before show/hide, which is more efficient ... if you are interested to learn that logic of course, as it is a better one for the future, and future readers. And checking a logic number is better than depend on a value

Comment: You know what, yours is validating and is a little bit more thought out, i will mark you as the right answer, thank you for helping.

Answer (score 2):

By making use of selected text you can do like

```
$('#category_faq').on('change', function () {
    if($(this).val() == "") {
        $('websitesubmission').show();
    } else {

       $('websitesubmission').hide();
       $('websitesubmission.' + $(this).val()).show()
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code:

```
$('#category_faq').on('change', function () {
    $('websitesubmission').hide();
    if($(this).val() != ""){
    $('websitesubmission.' + $(this).val()).show()
    }else{
    $('websitesubmission').show()
    }
});
```

Comment: My savior! You are a legend, your probably thinking it was an easy fix but I do not know Javascript very well. Thank you so much!

Comment: I marked you as the correct answer but a better solution was presented so I changed it over, while your code works and is perfect the refined version seems to agree with my validating program more. Thank you so much though, maybe someone in the future can use your solution as it does work and you were first.